# How to render an array of ( react component ) SVG elements so their z-index will be above it's adjacent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to render a list of react component svg elements with labels that appear on hover. Everything's working great except the labels render underneath their neighbour. I've tried reversing the order of the render function but it doesn't seem to work.

EG:

```
{data.reverse().map((d, i) => <StackedBars key={i} {...stackedBarProps[i]} /> )}
```

Comment: What do you mean by render above adjacent component? Could you perhaps upload an image of what is happening?

Comment: labels are svg elements?

Comment: everything is SVG and they z-Index is determined by the order they are rendered